# У меня Spring AOP через XML и конфигурации Java работают по-разному. Это мой баг или спринга?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Есть простая программа - бин App запускает разные реализации метода logEvent интерфейса EventLogger в зависимости от условий. В одной из реализаций запускаются 2 одноименных метода других реализаций. То есть в данном случае имеем вложенные вызовы методов разных классов с одним названием.
Эту программу реализовал в двух вариантах - через XML и с помощью конфигурационного класса. Результат работы идентичный.
Прикручиваю к этому аспект с поинтом на описанный выше метод. Эдвайс считает количество вызовов методов разных реализаций.

И вот тут начинаются чудеса!

В случае с XML все отлично работает, считает все, в том числе и вложенные вызовы.

В варианте с JAVA-конфигурациями эдвайс не срабатывает вообще.
Заставляю работать, вызывая не напрямую метод интерфейса, а через бин (так как там уже прокси). Но в этом случае эдвайс работает только на первых вызовах, на вложенных уже не нет. 
Вроде как и логично, ведь там тоже уже прокси и вокруг них надо тоже плясать...
Но почему всё работает через XML?

Я что-то сделал не так во втором варианте или это баг АОП Спринга?

**Это конфигурация через JAVA:**

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan("pro.thaipad.springtest1")
@Configuration
public class AppContext {

    @Bean
    public static App app() {
        App app = new App(cacheFileEventLogger(), loggerMap());
        return app;
    }

    @Bean (name = "ConsoleEventLogger")
    public static ConsoleEventLogger consoleEventLogger() {
        return new ConsoleEventLogger();
    }

    @Bean (name = "CombinedEventLogger")
    public static CombinedEventLogger combinedEventLogger() {
        return new CombinedEventLogger(combinedLoggers());
    }

    @Bean (name = "FileEventLogger")
    public static FileEventLogger fileEventLogger() {
        return new FileEventLogger("D:\\tmp\\spring1.log");
    }

    @Bean(name = "CacheFileEventLogger",initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public static CacheFileEventLogger cacheFileEventLogger() {
        return new CacheFileEventLogger("D:\\tmp\\spring1.log", 3);
    }

    @Bean
    public static DateFormat dateFormat() {
        return DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public static List<EventLogger> combinedLoggers() {
        List<EventLogger> loggers = new ArrayList<EventLogger>(2);
        loggers.add(consoleEventLogger());
        loggers.add(fileEventLogger());
        return loggers;
    }

    @Bean
    public static Map<EventType, EventLogger> loggerMap() {
        Map<EventType, EventLogger> map = new EnumMap<>(EventType.class);
        map.put(EventType.INFO, consoleEventLogger());
        map.put(EventType.ERROR, combinedEventLogger());
        return map;
    }

}
```

**Это аспект:**

```
@Aspect
@Component("statistics")
public class StatisticsAspect {
    private  Map<Class, Integer> countInvoke = new HashMap<>();

    @AfterReturning("execution(* *.logEvent(..))")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Class targetClass = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
        getCountInvoke().put(targetClass, getCountInvoke().getOrDefault(targetClass, 0) + 1);
    }

    public Map<Class, Integer> getCountInvoke() {
        return countInvoke;
    }
}
```

**Это класс App:**

```
public class App {
    private EventLogger defaultLogger;
    private Map<EventType, EventLogger> loggers;

    public App(EventLogger eventLogger, Map<EventType, EventLogger> loggers) {
        this.defaultLogger = eventLogger;
        this.loggers = loggers;
    }

    public EventLogger getDefaultLogger() {
        return defaultLogger;
    }

    public Map<EventType, EventLogger> getLoggers() {
        return loggers;
    }

    public void logEventApp(ApplicationContext context, EventType eventType, String msg) {
        EventLogger logger = getLoggers().get(eventType);
        if (logger == null) {
            logger = getDefaultLogger();
        }

        //logger.logEvent(msg);
        context.getBean(logger.getClass()).logEvent(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppContext.class);

        App app = (App) context.getBean("app");
        app.logEventApp(context, null,"Message 1");
        app.logEventApp(context, EventType.INFO, "Message 2");
        app.logEventApp(context, EventType.ERROR, "Message 3");

        StatisticsAspect statistics = (StatisticsAspect) context.getBean("statistics");
        statistics.getCountInvoke().forEach((c, i)-> System.out.println(c.getSimpleName() + ": " + i));

        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
    }
}
```

**Это конфигурация XML из работающей программы:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="pro.thaipad.springtestann"/>

    <import resource="maploggers.xml"/>

    <bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.DateFormat" factory-method="getDateTimeInstance"/>

    <bean id="consoleEventLogger" class="pro.thaipad.springtestann.eventlogger.ConsoleEventLogger" />

    <bean id="fileEventLogger" class="pro.thaipad.springtestann.eventlogger.FileEventLogger"
          init-method="init">
        <constructor-arg value="D:\tmp\spring.log"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheFileEventLogger" class="pro.thaipad.springtestann.eventlogger.CacheFileEventLogger"
          parent="fileEventLogger" destroy-method="destroy">
        <constructor-arg value="3"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="combinedEventLogger" class="pro.thaipad.springtestann.eventlogger.CombinedEventLogger">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="consoleEventLogger"/>
                <ref bean="fileEventLogger"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

<!--
        <bean id="statistics" class="pro.thaipad.springtestann.StatisticsAspect"/>
-->
    <bean id="app"
          class="pro.thaipad.springtestann.App"
          c:eventLogger-ref="cacheFileEventLogger"
          c:loggers-ref="loggerMap"/>

</beans>
```

Классы-логгеры простые, если нужно, выложу отдельно...
Версии:

```
<spring.ver>4.3.18.RELEASE</spring.ver>
<aspectj.ver>1.8.9</aspectj.ver>
```

**UPD:**
Нашел способ починить код, но не понял, почему так.
Бины-коллекции (у меня это List и Map) так не впрыскиваются. А вот передачу их через параметр Спринг понимает и связывает:

```
@Bean
public static App app(Map<EventType, EventLogger> loggerMap) {
    App app = new App(cacheFileEventLogger(), loggerMap);
    return app;
}
```

аналогично с листом:

```
@Bean (name = "combinedEventLogger")
    public static CombinedEventLogger combinedEventLogger(List<EventLogger> combinedLoggers) {
        return new CombinedEventLogger(combinedLoggers);
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать код очевиднее? Например, через ручное прописывание зависимостей @DependsOn...

Comment: Нашел способ починить код, но не понял, почему так.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Spring AOP: объясните, пожалуйста, что не так!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877130/spring-aop-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba)